# How do I use autossh to set up a no-frills socks proxy?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, socks, autossh

I use `ssh -D 12345 joeuser@somewhere.com` to set up dynamic port forwarding via host `somewhere.com`. I want to switch to using `autossh` to daemonize the thing and to make sure I don't need to manually monitor it.

I installed the autossh package (on my Linux Mint 18.1), but I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to do. Why aren't there any configuration/defaults files under `/etc/`? Where's the service which starts autossh tunnles? Do I need to do all of that manually?

Comment: Manual page for [`autossh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) should explain you everything.

Comment: @Jakuje: Very much unlikely, as it cannot tell me about distribution-level facilities for using autossh, such as init.d scripts / systemd services, `/etc/defaults/` files and so on.

Comment: ... indeed, the man does not even begin to answer my question.

Comment: No, there is no such service. If you wouls wqnt one, you need to write one.

Comment: `$ autossh -D localhost:1080 -N 'frank@5.1.2.5'`

Answer (score 4):

Explanation for fingerpich's answer:

- `autossh -f` causes autossh to drop to the background before running ssh.
- `-M` specifies a monitoring port for autossh to use.
- `-D` specifies the local socks proxy port
- `-N` specifies do not execute a remote command.  this is useful for just forwarding ports

If you don't want to use a monitoring port the following command instead uses SSH keep-alives every 10 seconds to detect failure:

```
autossh -f -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -D localhost:1234 -N user@ip.address
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://blog.michaelkelly.org/2010/12/easy-socks-proxy-with-autossh.html) and used the following command

```bsh
autossh -f -M 5731 -D localhost:1234 -N user@ip
```

Comment: Can you explain why this combination of switches is what we should use, and what exactly this will do?

Comment: You can find them using `man ssh` and `man autossh`.
I used it to make a reliable socks proxy

Comment: On SE websites, answers should be mostly self-contained and not essentially references. I can, indeed, find them, but the answer should be expanded nonetheless.

Comment: thanks, but I just tried to share a solution